# How to stop while loop button when bot receives different data from another button Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

@dp.message_handler()
async def starting(message: types.Message):

```
if message.text == "August 27":
    while True:
        August()
        await message.answer(August(),reply_markup=data_change_markup)
if message.text == "Change data ":
    #Here, I want to stop while True from "August 27"
    await message.answer('Alright, we will change the data', reply_markup=data_markup)
```